# ValueError con RegularGridInterpolator (Scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolacion

Necesito ayuda con la función `RegularGridInterpolator` de Scipy, explico:

Tengo 3 listas de largo 1000 con mediciones (`data_1`, `data_2`, `data_3`), que están asociadas con soluciones químicas, que es un arreglo que va de 2 a 10 y tiene un largo de 1000 (es como si las soluciones químicas fueran el "eje x" y las mediciones el "eje y", para que se entienda) y quiero relacionar estas 3 mediciones con esta función. Desarrollé el siguiente código pero me da un error.

El código:

```
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import numpy as np

x = data_1
y = data_2
z = data_3
data = interp_c # soluciones químicas 

xg, yg, zg = np.meshgrid(data, data, data, indexing='ij', sparse=True)

interp = RegularGridInterpolator((xg, yg, zg), data)
```

Este es el error que entrega:
`ValueError: There are 3 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions`

Los datos son de este tipo:

```
x = array([ 94.59      ,  94.54839196,  94.50678392,  94.46517588,
        94.42356784,  94.3819598 ,  94.34035176,  94.29874372,...])

data = array([ 2.        ,  2.04020101,  2.08040201,  2.12060302,  2.16080402,
        2.20100503,  2.24120603,  2.28140704,  2.32160804,  2.36180905,
        2.40201005,  2.44221106,  2.48241206,  2.52261307,  2.56281407,
        2.60301508,  2.64321608,  2.68341709,  2.72361809,  2.7638191 ,
        2.8040201 ,  2.84422111,  2.88442211,  2.92462312,  2.96482412,
        3.00502513,  3.04522613,  3.08542714,  3.12562814,  3.16582915,...])
```

Me basé en un código ejemplo y cambié los datos, no comprendo cuál es el error, ayuda!

Comment: Lo que se puede decir con lo poco que muestras, es que data no contiene los valores adecuados. Sugiero que incluyas un [mcve], con los datos, para poder verificar.

Comment: @jachguate muchas gracias por la sugerencia, agregué muestras de los datos con algunos valores (son arreglos de largo 1000, por lo que solo puse algunos)